# renderInContext does not work correctly when changing layer Z position

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, calayer

My application allow user to switch `UIImageView` back and front and then user can capture that screen. Here is my code to capture the screen into `UIImage`

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 2.0f);

// I even tried view.layer.presentationLayer but still not working
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


return image;

}
```

I do not use `[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]` because it is slower and sometimes (when view is not visible) drawn the screenshot in black.

But problem with renderInContext is the Z position that change between `UIImageView  ( imageView.layer.zPosition = 0.01;etc )`. In my iPhone screen this work correctly when I assigned value to zPosition but in the capture screen it turns out wrong.

Are there anyway I can resolve this problem ? Thanks in advance

Edited: 
Here is what I tried to do before capture the screenshot. I use this code to make one ImageView display in front of another one.

```
-(void)bringOneLevelUp:(UIImageView*)imageView
{
//_imgArray is sorted by Z position order (small to big)
    NSUInteger currentObjectIndex = [_imgArray indexOfObject:imageView];


if(currentObjectIndex+1< _imgArray.count){

UIImageView *upperImageView = [_imgArray objectAtIndex:currentObjectIndex+1];


    CGFloat currentZIndex = imageView.layer.zPosition;
    CGFloat upperZIndex= upperImageView.layer.zPosition;

    imageView.layer.zPosition = upperZIndex;
    upperImageView.layer.zPosition = currentZIndex;


// swap position in array 
[_imgArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:currentObjectIndex withObjectAtIndex:currentObjectIndex+1];

}
```

}

And liked I explained earlier the result of this code in the phone screen is correct. The newImageView is in front of lastImageView.  But when I captured screenshot by renderInContext. They are not.

Comment: What does "turns out wrong" mean?  What z-position values are you trying?

Comment: I swapped z position of UIImageView. It looks correct in the phone screen but not when I tried capturing it.

Comment: I don't really understand exactly what your code is doing.  Why haven't you shown it in your question?

Comment: I have added the code you asked for. But it has nothing to do. The problem is renderInContext does not capture the zPosition of the view layer. And I tried using  layer.presentationLayer. But it is still not working correctly

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

The answer of @RameshVel worked for me translating it to **Swift**, maybe someone needs this:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingCanvas.frame.size)
 self.renderInContext(ct: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

 guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {return}
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

And in the renderInContext function:

```
 func renderInContext(ct:CGContext){

    ct.beginTransparencyLayer(auxiliaryInfo: nil)

    // descendant ordered list of views based on its z-position
    let orderedLayers = self.view.subviews.sorted(by: {
        $0.layer.zPosition < $1.layer.zPosition
    })

    for l in orderedLayers {
        l.layer.render(in: ct)
    }
    ct.endTransparencyLayer()
}
```

The same can be donde with **CALayers** if you are drawing and adding layers:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingCanvas.frame.size)
 //Canvas is a custom UIView for drawing
 self.renderInContext(ct: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!, canvas: canvas)

 guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {return}
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

renderInContext function:

```
func renderInContext(ct:CGContext, canvas:CustomCanvas){

    ct.beginTransparencyLayer(auxiliaryInfo: nil)
    let layers:[CALayer] = canvas.layer.sublayers!

    let orderedLayers = layers.sorted(by: {
        $0.zPosition < $1.zPosition
    })

    for v in orderedLayers {
        v.render(in: ct)
    }
    ct.endTransparencyLayer()
}
```

Comment: this does not seem to render the sublayers in the correct positions or with the correct rotation.  Does one have to add something to make sure the sublayers are rendered in the correct positions ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. I wanted text to draw on top of an image after using renderInContext(). I solved this by positioning my views when adding them to the window rather than using the layer to set the z-position.

I used to have a text field that would set its z-position upward:

```
layer?.zPosition = 1
```

I removed this code and instead, when adding my image to the window, I used:

```
addSubview(image, positioned: .Below, relativeTo: nil)
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and its a bummer.

I know this question was asked about 2 years ago, so heres the answer anyway if it helps anyone incase

So changing subviews `zPosition` renders perfectly fine in the app but in fact affects the `renderByContext` when used to create a screenshot. I don't know why, I assume it's a bug.

So in order to get the screenshot to appear correctly as it renders in the app, we need to manually call the `renderByContext` on all subviews in the correct order as specified by zPosition.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and

```
-(void) renderInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(ctx, NULL);
    //self.layers is a desc ordered list of views based on its zPosition
    for(UIView *view in self.layers){ 
        [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    }
    CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(ctx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying bug of Apple's, but the solution is easy, simply re-order the view you are snapshotting's subviews (and their subviews (and so on)) recursively, based on their zPositions, using a comparator.

Just call the following method, passing the view you are about to snapshot, directly before snapshotting it.

```
///UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext doesn't obey layer zPositions so have to adjust view heirarchy (integer index) to match zpositions (float values) for all nested subviews.
-(void)recursivelyAdjustHeirarchyOfSubviewsBasedOnZPosition:(UIView *)parentView {

    NSArray *sortedSubviews = [[parentView subviews] sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                           ^NSComparisonResult(UIView *view1, UIView *view2)
                           {
                               float zpos1 = view1.layer.zPosition;
                               float zpos2 = view2.layer.zPosition;
                               return zpos1 > zpos2;
                           }];

    for (UIView *childView in sortedSubviews) {
        [parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
        [self recursivelyAdjustHeirarchyOfSubviewsBasedOnZPosition:childView];
    }

}
```